# AZURE Worker Role Deploy with extra DLL's and app.Config

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I'm trying to deploy an Azure Worker Role Cloud Service.  When testing a "Hello World" scenario, it's very simple and works fine.

Once I add references to custom DLL's, and EntityFramework, the Worker Role will no longer deploy.  My thought is the extra DLL's and the app.config file is not getting deployed.

Here is the error:

1:25:03 PM - Uploading Package...

1:25:57 PM - Updating...

1:29:04 PM - Your role instances have recycled a number of times during an update or upgrade operation. This indicates that the new version of your service or the configuration settings you provided when configuring the service prevent the role instances from running. Verify your code does not throw unhandled exceptions and that your configuration settings are correct and then start another update or upgrade operation.

Does anyone know why it's failing and if this is possible or how to deploy a more complex worker role?

Comment: Did you test using Compute emulator on local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is present locally that doesn't exist (or is not available) once deployed.

Easiest thing to do is remotely debug your worker role:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff683670.aspx#BK_Debugging_Cloud_Azure

Answer (score 0):

Both feedback items helped me resolve the error.  Below are the steps:

1.)  I made sure I had both a  web site and worker role added to the solution.

2.)  I verified they both ran and could be published to Azure.

3.)  I then added my custom code, and ensured the config file for the worker role was correct and working in the compute emulator.

4.)  I ensured the app.config and dll files had the property copy local to true, which ensured they were deployed.

5.) Deployed to Azure and it worked!

Thanks...